# how to install plyr >=1.8.1 package for R version 3.0.2 for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

```
> library(plyr)
> library(ggplot2)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘plyr’ 1.8 is already loaded, but >= 1.8.1 is required
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

earlier plyr packages was working fine but now it was uninstalled by mistake and now i m trying to reinstall it again .It display the above error

Comment: Upgrade your version of R first.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+package/r-cran-plyr

Choose the version you need from the Published versions section, then on the right you will see Downloadable files.

They are debs so no compiling required.

Comment: The OP asked about 14.04, not 15.04.  These are deb package with compiled code so you can't generally just pick them randomly.  This is bad advice, consider removing the answer.

Comment: Well you are now both rude and clueless.  You are mixing the R package system with the one from the distro, and you are using the latter the wrong way.

Comment: Oh, AND they will have been created by the wrong R version.

Comment: First, update R:

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu quantal/' >>  /etc/apt/sources.list" 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
Then install codetools package from R:

install.packages("codetools")
After this, the installation of plyr go smoothly.

Comment: Still wrong.  While the CRAN repos are a good idea, they *assume that your R version is current* whereas OP specifically stated that this version is 3.0.2.  You provide him with an upgrade path (which is helpful) but it is not what he asked for.  Anyway, the question is a FAQ and I pointed to a better (collected) answer already on SO.